# At least one checkboxe validation will only work if a checkbox is checked on current pagination page. jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am trying to validate checkbox and make sure the user select at least one checkbox before submitting the form. Validation work when a checkbox is select on the current pagination page. if I don't select a checkbox on the current pagination page but I selected one on the other page the validation failed and I don't know why

View

```
 <table id="tblBulckTicket" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover datatable responsive" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>

                        </th>
                        <th>

                            @Html.Label("id", "Ticket ID")
                        </th>
               </thead>
            <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="TicketId"  value="@item.Id">     
                            </td>   
                            <td>                                   
                             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                     }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var table =   $('#tblBulckTicket').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 5
        });
   }

 // Checkbox validation
   $(function () {
        $('input[id$=btnSubmit]').click(function (ze) {
        var checkbox = $('#tblBulckTicket').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0;
            if (!checkbox) {
                $('#Ticket').css('display', 'block');
                $('#Ticket').text('At least One  Ticket Should Be Selected');
                ze.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                $('#Ticket').css('display', 'block');
                $('#Ticket').text('');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean I select checkbox on previous page? If you change page and url validation certainly will not work unless you keep some data in user session and adjust accordingly

Comment: @Nikos if I have 2 pages pagination I selected a checkbox on page 2 and when I submit the form I am on page 1 and I did not select a checkbox on page 1 the validation failed